# How is this equation obtained?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, aerodynamics, vortex

I'm trying to code a script to solve aerodynamics problems with different numerical methods. I'm analyzing one method, in which I'm particularly stuck because I need to obtain a velocity equation, but I don't know how to justify it (because this is not my field).

Given the scheme of the problem:

[image: Scheme horseshoe vortex]

That shows a rectangular wing, with a horseshoe vortex on it. The intensity of the vortex is $\Gamma$, the finite vortex line crosses the wing at $1/4c$ and the control point is in the center at $3/4c$. Where $c$ is the chord of the wing, and $b$ the wingspan.

The velocity expression I have to obtain is the following:

[image]

And it is the velocity induced by the vortex in the control point.

I'm having problems in calculating the distances that are between brackets in the equation. The multiplicative factor $\Gamma/(4\pi)$ is shown by Prandtl Wing Theory.

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to compute the distances within the brackets, because I have tried on a paper several ways but I don't understand how it is obtained. Since I don't have the original equation for this method and I only have this numerical example, I'm having a hard time to guess how it is computed.